# What is the Story of Vishnu's incarnation Chaitanya?

Tags: vishnu, bhavishya-purana, avatars

What is the Story of Vishnu's incarnation Chaitanya?

> According to Bhavishya Puran  Lord Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was an
>   incarnation of Lord Sri Krishna.

My Question is What Story Behind this Incarnation Of Vishnu?